# Meaning of the expression "put me on perkies"

Tags: meaning

I am reading a book (Pump Six and Other Stories by Paolo Bacigalupi, for that matters) in which one of the characters wants to have a son with his wife. One day he has a terrible nightmare about the child beeing physically malformed, and recalling it he thinks:

> That dream scared me limp for a month. Maggie put me on perkies because of it.

So, **what does the expression "put me on perkies" mean**?

Comment: *put me on my perkies = made me happy.*

Comment: @Subjunctive - that interpretation wouldn't make much sense for this context. I get the impression that "perkies" here might be slang for Viagra.

Comment: @J.R. - coould it be slang for antidepressants, I wonder.

Comment: @CopperK - Sure, it could be, but there's something about the phrase "scared me limp" in the context of trying to conceive a child that makes me think Viagra rather than Prozac.

Comment: I am not familiar with the term **perkies** except as the nickname for the narcotic Percoset.

Comment: Perco**c**et (oxycodone) for treating anxiety: https://www.healthtap.com/user_questions/555460-can-percocet-oxycodone-acetaminophen-help-treat-anxiety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To put somebody on something,** is to tell somebody to start taking a particular medicine (or eating particular foods), so if "perkies" is short for "Perkocet", a narcotic pain meditation,then Maggie started giving him this medication to deal with his fear.